# python subprocess with failed command return code 0

Tags: python, subprocess

I execute the following code in both windows cmd and ubuntu bash:

```
python -c "import xxx"
```

Error messages output. And when I run:

```
echo $? / echo %errorlevel%
```

The value is 1.

When I do the same task in python script with subprocess as follows:

```
cmdlst = ['python', '-c', '“import xxx”‘]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdlst)
retcode = proc.wait()
```

The retcode is 0.
What is the problem and how can I get the correct return code of the command
run within a subprocess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh? The "smart quotes" you're using here aren't valid syntax at all.

Comment: (that is to say, `'“import xxx”‘` is a very different thing from `'"import xxx"'`, and the former -- which is what is included in the question -- **wouldn't** exit with status 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the shell command (equivalent to your given `subprocess.Popen()` call if we disregard the use of "smart quotes")

```
'python' '-c' '"import xxx"'
```

**correctly exits with status 0, whether or not a module named xxx exists**.

This is because `"import xxx"` is a string, and evaluating a string does not throw an exception. You'd get the exact same behavior from `python -c '"hello world"'`, or any other string.

---

If you really want to try executing the code `import xxx`, then you need to remove the extra quotes:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'import xxx']).wait()
```

...will properly return `1` (if no `xxx` module exists).

Comment: I've got it. Thanks